# ¿Cómo cambiar de un edittext a otro con el botón 'enter'? Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

Cómo puedo cambiar el foco de un edittext a otro edittext pulsando el botón enter o si se pudiera cambiar el botón enter por alguno de siguiente, he investigado, pero no he encontrado casi nada en Xamarin Android, me mencionaron éste método pero no he logrado utilizarlo

```
txtUser.ImeOptions = global::Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Next;
```

Comment: Existen varias formas.
1.- Asignarle un Listener keyTiped al editText y verificar si el character ingresado es igual a enter. Ejemplo: setKeyListener y con eso podrías saber si la tecla ingresada es enter
2.- Esta opción no resultó la probé.
3.- crear un listener que te diga cuando se usa enter. Y hacer que se pase al siguiente componente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probá en el XML:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:hint="Email" />
```

- **`actionNone`** :  Este editor no tiene ninguna acción asociada.
- **`actionGo`** : La tecla de acción realiza una operación "ir" para llevar al usuario al destino del texto que escribió. Normalmente se usa, por ejemplo, al ingresar una URL.
- **`actionSearch`** : La tecla de acción realiza una operación de "búsqueda", llevando al usuario a los resultados de la búsqueda del texto que ha escrito (en el contexto que sea apropiado).
- **`actionSend`** : La tecla de acción realiza una operación de "envío", entregando el texto a su destino. Esto se usa generalmente al redactar un mensaje.
- **`actionNext`** : La tecla de acción realiza una "próxima" operación, llevando al usuario al siguiente campo que aceptará texto.
- **`actionDone`** : La tecla de acción realiza una operación "finalizar", cerrando el método de entrada.

Acá se pueden ver todos los tipos de `imeOptions`:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Resource+Attribute.ImeOptions/

Comment: Podrias descrirbir mas como llegaste a esta solución